# Custom curvy shape for a CardView in android

Tags: android, android-cardview

I've just started with android and, in order to learn something, i'm simply trying to recreate some basic concept that i found on the web. My biggest question so far is which is the best method to draw a custom curvy shape in android. I know that similar question have been asked multiple times here, but i'm unable to find the solution to my problem.

[image: Link to concept to recreate]

I do not understand how to replicate a card like this. My only idea so far is to create curvy line in illustrator, save into svg and import in android as vector assets. At this point i was simply thinking to create a white rectangle and overlay the vectori assets. I absolutely don't think this is teh best way to do it but so far i don't know another way.

Thanks and sorry my english

Comment: see `VectorDrawable`

Comment: but honestly i would create a custom `android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape` class for that...

Comment: How can i do that? how do i use this class after?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/Shape

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

either user CardView or create your custom view.

**CardView**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/scale_7dp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/scale_5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Custom View**
create a shape in your drawable.xml folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/dull_white" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/scale_5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/scale_5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/scale_5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="@dimen/scale_5dp" />
</shape>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: ok, i understand how to do this. My concern is how to draw the middle curvy line from the conceppt that separates two different colours

Comment: You can achieve this by using canvas. Please check this https://github.com/narayanacharya6/WaveView

Comment: Thanks, works but with a problem. This view override every try to insert a corner radius to the parent views. Corners disappear

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in app, this lib will give a rounded corner Image and other for cardview.

```
 implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

In xml parent CardView and its Child RoundedImageView have same corner radius. I hope you know, how cardview works. Where "YOUR_DRAWABLE_HERE" is written please change it with your drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#00ffffff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">
            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_look"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="YOUR_DRAWABLE_HERE"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:riv_corner_radius="10dp"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />


                <TextView
                    android:text="YOUR TEXT"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Picture after implementation]

Comment: It's best to add some explanation outside of your code snippet

Comment: Sorry my inexperience but i'm unable to get this working. I've simple updateted and sync my gradle with the new implementation and then copy-pasted you xml code. in every app: ... string the complier says namespace app is not bound. Where is my mistake?

Comment: please try now after implementation of dependency. I hope this will help you. I added namespaces.

Comment: now says that the support.CardViewLibrary versione is incompatibile vith my project. It says I shold use v28. Maybe it's for implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'? Never touched that line

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc01' use this. it will solve incompatible version issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best implementation would be to use CardView in your layout.
include

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
```

or any other version which is compatible with your existing support library.

after that, use this in your layout xml file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey_300"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

place all the other views inside this cardview and you will get a curvy edge.